# Scollbar scrolls too fast in IE and Edge

Tags: html, internet-explorer, iframe, scroll, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to embed an iframe on a page, however, my page is very long, and thus the iframe is very long. The problem is when the page is very long, in IE and Edge, for every tick of the mousewheel, instead of scrolling only 2 to 3 lines as in Chrome, it scrolls 10+ lines at once. It scrolls too fast.

```
<iframe src="longpage.html" style="height:6000px"></iframe>
```

This only happens in IE and Edge. Does anyone have any ideas on how to limit the scroll to only 3 lines per tick?

Here's an example: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/4ksnlfT71t8d0hRH6VkU?p=preview

View in IE/Edge to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

There is this great plugin. You can try it, though it may not work for ie  as I see it is "Disabled for performance"

https://github.com/nathco/jQuery.scrollSpeed

As a side note I would not recommend doing this as this plugin and all others only simulate scroll speed change and can affect performance usability of your webpage.

Scroll speed is determined by the browser or the device itself.

Comment: @uneatenbreakfast was this helpful to you?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, it's a step in the right direction, unfortunately it doesn't work for IE/Edge, which is my target browser(s).